# Stop Domains from Pointing to my server I.P

Tags: ubuntu, server

I recently created an Ubuntu server and installed LEMP stack after which I hosted my website on the server using WordPress.

But after sometime, I notices some domains ranking in Google and loading my website.

Is there any way through which I can stop them from doing this?

Previously, I never faced such issue.

For reference:
My main domain: https://droidmaze.com

Other domains (not mine) pointing to my server I.P.:

```
http://tirtadji.com/
http://www.pisonlifetree.com
```

I am concerned that this can penalize my website for duplicate content.

Thanks.

Comment: Do you know what happens when someone accesses one of those other domains?  Maybe someone is hijacking your server through a WordPress bug.

Comment: They are displaying kind of a copy of my website.

Comment: I'm afraid dealing with people who copy your web site is off-topic for StackOverflow. If instead someone is pointing their domain name at your web site, see this related question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/101007/somebody-elses-domain-name-is-pointing-to-my-server-ip-address-and-google-is-in - in this case your question is about configuring nginx, not "LEMP".

Answer (score 0):

I think it's already solved in OP's webmaster's question(https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/131250/how-to-stop-domains-from-pointing-to-my-server-ip-address-and-duplicating-my-sit). Moderators can mark this one duplicate or close this one.